# What method must be implemented to receive a file from another app using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Using Swift, what method do you need to implement in order to act on an incoming file (e.g. a user clicking on an email attachment which has a file type specified by your app's Document Type / Exported UTI)?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781290/460638) answer which refers to using the ObjC method `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  The equivalent in Swift would be:

`func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {...}`

but I'm not clear on the implementation details to handle the incoming file.  Is the file dropped into some folder accessible to the receiving app?  Is there a URL to the file?

How do you implement the receipt of the file in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are handed a file in this way, it goes into your Inbox folder (which is created, if necessary, in your Documents folder).

Documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html